# why ng-change not fired in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

could you please tell me why ng-change not fired in angular js ? when I  type "abc" in date input field it fire only one time . please tell me how I will fire multiple time
here is my code

```
$scope.changedate =function(){
    console.log('asda')
  }

<li ng-repeat="(key, x) in c">
       <p class="input-group"  ng-if="x.date=='date'">
          <input type="text" ng-change='changedate()' class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="x.name" is-open="x.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="formats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1(x)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      <input id='{{key}}' ng-if="x.date!='date'"  type="text" ng-model='x.name' value="{{x.name=='abc'?'ddd':'hhh'}}"/>
    </li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/neixp9ZARRAQ33gKSV9u?p=preview
tep to reproduce this error

1. Run the application .First  date field is empty .I just entered `1` inside that then ng changed fired and after that aagin i type anthing it doesn't fire

Comment: Please share code in your question. You can use snippet to create executable code as well

Comment: I already share plunker link

Comment: please explain more

Comment: without the error its hard to tell whats wrong with your code. My suggestion press f12 to open the chrome developer console. and see what the error is on the console. secondly i noticed that you haven't given the name of your controller module in the html file. before "ng-controller" u also need to give it the module " ng-app='app' ".

Comment: @user944513 Reason I asked you to share your code is because your question should be independent on its own. Sharing a link means users need to visit another link to view your problem. Also, there are chances where such site are not available.

Comment: @user944513 Also, should `ng-change='changedate()'` not be `ng-change='changedate'`. Not sure though

Comment: @Rajesh ng-change='changedate()' is for calling a function changedate would be a variable. so its fine.

Comment: please see the update

Comment: it's working as a function

Comment: @user944513 Your plunker code is not reproducing the same scenario with me at least. It has abc written on the input field already and nothing happens if i change anything in it. if ng-change is not working right then there is an error on the console kindly tell us the error.

Comment: so it fires only one time but not in second time

Comment: when you change value with datepicker popup, it works but you type a text, it doesnt work for second time, if you want change it after type you can use ng-keypress='changedate()' and you want change it after focusout you can ng-blur='changedate()'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has edited the PLNKR to ask a new question. The PLUNKR no longer applies to this question. The question no longer has a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example and is not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

because when you type `a`, the model value become `undefined`, when you type `b`, the model value is undefined so nothing has changed, when you type `c` the model is again `undefined`. that is why `ng-change` is not called.

from angularjs documentation:

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated:
>
> if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
>   not changed if the input has continued to be invalid since the model
>   will stay null if the model is changed programmatically and not by a
>   change to the input value

here is a helper directive I use for such senario:

```
angular.module('viewValueChanged', [])
    .directive('viewValueChanged', viewValueChangedDirective);


function viewValueChangedDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linkFn
    };

    function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return ngModel.$viewValue;
        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                scope.$parent.$eval(attrs['viewValueChanged']);
            }
            // in case of user entered invalid value
            if(newValue === null) {
                scope.$parent.$eval(attrs['viewValueChanged']);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
 <input uib-datepicker-popup view-value-changed="vm.onFieldsChange() />
```